# Editing cleared

Tags: support, questions

After I edit a question before, it said something like 'It has to be approved before it is reflected. The edit is only available to you'. But, now, it doesn't show anything, and the edit that I made is simply cleared. Was there a change on the system, or is my edit rejected automatically, or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your edit seems to get rejected.

examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/23789
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/23788
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/23786
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/23785
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/23783
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/23777
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/23776

Probably, people think just removing salutation, is not really useful edit, so your edits got rejected. once you hit limit of rejected edits, you will lose edit right for a week (may be), so please take care with that.

Comment: It is rejected at the point I submit. Does that mean any edit that I make will be refected?

Comment: @sawa, only the edit to that particular answer/question got rejected by reviewers. so it will not be reflected.